# JavaScript Scope Clarification

Tags: javascript, event-handling, scope, this

I've been reading just about every article I can get my hands on about JavaScript scope to better understand it. I'd like to perfectly understand it by the end. I'm currently reading this article: http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/ and I've just finished reading the "Complications" section (a little more than halfway down) and thought it was very helpful, but not quite clear enough.

It uses the following code and considers the `onclick` behavior of `the_button`:

```
function BigComputer(answer) { 
  this.the_answer = answer; 
  this.ask_question = function () { 
   alert(this.the_answer); 
  } 
} 

function addhandler() { 
  var deep_thought = new BigComputer(42), 
   the_button = document.getElementById('thebutton'); 

  the_button.onclick = deep_thought.ask_question; 
} 

window.onload = addhandler;
```

The article states `... an event handler[,] runs in a different context than when it’s executed as an object method.` So, if I'm to understand correctly, then the call to the `ask_question` method in context of the script's object method is `deep_thought.ask_question`, making `this` `deep_thought`. But when an event in the DOM is triggered, then the call chain changes to `DOMelement.eventHandler.deep_thought.ask_question` making `this` `DOMelement`?

Comment: You are correct in your assumption, is there any further clarification you need? [Soshnikov](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/) is my favorite resource on JavaScript internals.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think I'm on the right track still, and I'll definitely look into that resource! I've heard a lot about Soshnikov in the JS community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct! 'this' in event handlers is the element you bound to. In this case it would be `the_button`. The alert would be 'undefined' as `the_button` has no `the_answer` property.

You can see an example at: http://jsfiddle.net/zG7KR/

See what this outputs:

```
this.ask_question = function () { 
     alert(this.the_answer);
};
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the JSFiddle example! I really should start using that more. ^^

Comment: I love it! It's such an awesomely simple way to get a quick prototype or example up!